# Block words from getting out the page

Tags: html, css

I'm using php to echo words from data, now the data might have long words length, about 50 words without using `<br />`.
Since the outpost doesn't have `<br />` tag he got scrolling right (x) option (I know I can use `overflow-x: hidden;` but thats not it).

**CSS**

```
.main-text{
    padding-left: 250px;
    margin: -160px 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.autobody{
    width: 101.4%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -15px -10px;
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 101.4%;
}
```

My question is how can I block words from getting out the page without hidden the content? (the content from php data)

Example Image With `Overflow-x: hidden;`

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/1291/m8w.png

Example Image Without `Overflow-x: hidden;`

http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/9567/fqn.png

Comment: You need to remove the `pre` tag from your fiddle if you want `word-wrap: break-word` to work.

Comment: But then i wont have any spaces from php outpost..

Comment: `pre` is going to cause the text to layout exactly as it is (i.e. if all one line then it will remain all one line.)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot remove the `pre` tag from personal reasons, is there any other way?

Comment: @yotam "I cannot remove the pre tag ... is there any other way" - no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

in the css
or if you want to use PHP to add the

```
wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n", true);
```

see [the wordwrap function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) for more info

Comment: Tried the word wrap function ? You also need a fixed width set on the div

Answer (score 4):

Try this CSS:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QK5Hv/)

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm trying to add it into main-text, but that not change anything.

Comment: @yotam it actually worked fine. For example, I set `.main-text` to `200px` and you get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xDZCX/2/). Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great CSS property for that: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Try `word-wrap: break-word;`